# Injection of autowired dependencies failed when using singleton pattern, AOP

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-aop

I have a CommandService class which used Singleton patterns, so it has a private constructors. Before I use AOP, I use the `getInstance()` method to returns a bean in `Application.java` like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"hello","wodinow.weixin.jaskey"})
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    LogUtil.info("Beans provided by Spring Boot:");
    String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    Arrays.sort(beanNames);
    for (String beanName : beanNames) {
        LogUtil.info(beanName);
    }
    LogUtil.info("Application Boots completes!");
}

//here I use a getInstance() to return that bean 
@Bean  
public CommandService commandService(){
    return CommandService.getInstance();
}
```

My `Controller` uses this class and need Spring to auto wire it.

```
@Controller
public class CoreController {

    @Autowired
    private CommandService commandService;
    ...
}
```

This works fine before I introduces AOP.

And after I use something like this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LogAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* wodinow.weixin.jaskey..*.*(..))")
    private void debug_log(){};

    @AfterReturning("debug_log()")
    public void debug(JoinPoint joinPoint){
        LogUtil.debug("returns from "+joinPoint.getSignature());
    }

}
```

My application fails when I run Application.java

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'coreController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.CommandService wodinow.weixin.jaskey.co.CoreController.commandService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commandService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.RoomService wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.CommandService.roomService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roomService' defined in class wodinow.weixin.jaskey.config.Application: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.RoomService]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.RoomService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at wodinow.weixin.jaskey.config.Application.main(Application.java:22)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.CommandService wodinow.weixin.jaskey.co.CoreController.commandService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commandService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.RoomService wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.CommandService.roomService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roomService' defined in class wodinow.weixin.jaskey.config.Application: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.RoomService]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.RoomService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commandService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.RoomService wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.CommandService.roomService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roomService' defined in class wodinow.weixin.jaskey.config.Application: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.RoomService]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.RoomService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:527)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.RoomService wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.CommandService.roomService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roomService' defined in class wodinow.weixin.jaskey.config.Application: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.RoomService]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.RoomService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roomService' defined in class wodinow.weixin.jaskey.config.Application: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.RoomService]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.RoomService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:548)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:527)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.RoomService]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.RoomService
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:212)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:445)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:331)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors in class wodinow.weixin.jaskey.service.RoomService
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.filterConstructors(Enhancer.java:531)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:448)
    at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:202)
    ... 47 more
```

My `CommandService` is like:

```
public class CommandService {

private static CommandService instance = new CommandService();

    @Autowired
    private RoomService roomService;//this is a class uses the same singleton patterns as `CommandService` does, and it has the same problem.

    //private constructor
    public CommandService() {}

    // singleton patterns
    public static CommandService getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    ...something else
 }
```

I know that spring by default will return only one instance everytime I need, but what if I do need the constructor to be private ,in case somebody else uses that constructor.

Thank you!

Comment: please post CommandService code

Comment: @SanketPipariya, Please review the question, thank you!

Comment: Post the full stack trace. Also you shouldn't use the singleton pattern as it is basically an anti pattern. Spring beans are singleton by default that should be enough.

Comment: @M.Deinum, If I use public constructors, there will be no issue here. But what if I really hope to not let others to create a brand new object in any ways, so the private constructor should make sense, why does it work before I introduce AOP? I will post the full stack after a minutes.

Comment: And why wouldn't others be allowed to create an object? Even a private constructor isn't a guarantee, using reflection I could still create an instance of the class (Spring with XML does this also). Given it is a little harder but there is no guarantee no-one will create another instance.

Comment: @M.Deinum, well just want to be sure only one instance is created, ins n't this what singleton does? Would you please explain that why introducing AOP will have this problem(What has to be prepared when we want to use Spring AOP), and why singleton is considered  as a anti pattern?

Comment: Because there is no guarantee and it is a singleton per class loader and not per JVM. AOP is a problem here because a class based proxy is made, for that proxy the class is extended however with only a private constructor that isn't possible, make it default or protected or use interfaces.